# ember.js hbs view helper in TextFieldView

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

i am new to ember.js. I have a custom view helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('translate', function(value, options) {
    return JoblyApp.i18n.__(value) || options.hash.def;
});
```

I need to apply this helper in the TextField:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="somevalue" placeholder="{{translate "city_or_region"}}" }}
```

how can i achieve this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use handlebar helpers inside other handlebar helpers. I would work around this by extending the `Ember.TextField` to translate the placeholder automatically.

I have created this [JSBin demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uYApacU/1/edit). *Note: It doesn't translate, it uses a dummy function to just uppercase the placeholder text. Replace with your function.*

### Extended Input:

```
JoblyApp.TranslateableTextFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        for(var key in this){
            if(key.substr(0,2)==="t_"){
                var value = this.get(key);
                this.set(key.substr(2, key.length - 2), JoblyApp.i18n.__(value));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Usage:

```
{{view JoblyApp.TranslateableTextFieldView valueBinding="somevalue" t_placeholder="city_or_region"}}
```

Note I have used `t_` as the prefix to search for, not `__` as Ember uses this key on private members of it's object. So I would avoid using this to prefix to prevent collisions.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you transform this to a general solution: lets say we loop over each attribute which has "i18n" in it, like placeholder. Or __placeholder and __title and so on. For each of these we set the value to the translated value. That would be great. So question is how can i iterate over all attributes? Because there is likely more than the placeholder to be translated.

Comment: got it 
`JoblyApp.TranslateableTextFieldView= Ember.TextField.extend({
didInsertElement: function() {
   for (var key in this) {

    if (key.substr(0,2) == '__') {

     keyName = key.substr(2, key.length);

     var value = this.get(key);

     this.set(keyName,JoblyApp.i18n.__(value));


    }

   }

  }

});`

Comment: @Amo Thanks, you got there a bit quicker than me that time. I have updated my code to use the generic method you asked for. I have used a prefix of `t_` instead of `__` to avoid clashes with Ember's object members.

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick:

```
App.TranslateableTextFieldView= Ember.TextField.extend({
      didInsertElement: function() {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (key.substr(0,2) == '__') {
                var keyName = key.substr(2, key.length);
                var value = this.get(key);
                this.set(keyName,App.i18n.__(value));
            }
        }
      }
    });
```